# Ubuntu get stuck on boot

Tags: installation, boot, logo

It seems that I can't install any OS on my system, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora or Mac OSX
except Windows, it just stuck on Ubuntu logo, or a little bit later and the same thing happened to Fedora and Mint.

I tried to install this on my laptop and it worked, so the disc isn't the problem. I tried to change to AHCI instead of IDE as suggested to me before but still no success.

PC specs:

- ASUS P6T Deluxe
- i7 940
- 580 gtx
- 12G

Comment: Try running Ubuntu's Livecd with your drive disconnected.

Comment: just tried.. no luck \=

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem when trying to install the 10.04 on an laptop. After changing the harddisk, the problem is gone. You could try.

Comment: i actually changed my hdd not long ago, i can check another one i guess. the problem in my PC.. on the laptop it did just fine. you think this is the problem anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your haddrive is fine. I can't get why it failed, but, if you have two graphic cards, try the built-in one instead of the external one.

this is to make sure it's not a graphic problem.

Comment: i was just thinking that, and then i realized i dont have internal one on my motherboard.. any other way to check it?

Comment: Hey i just borrowd a graphic card from a friend and it seems to work on his card! he has a 480GT and i have 580GTX.. i just recentlly bought the card so i dont think there is a problem with it.. any suggestions?

Comment: great, so, it does a graphic problem. your problam is common a bit. also I didn't saw a solution.